# Troublesome 2D array realloc heap error

Tags: c, visual-studio, heap-memory, realloc

Code snippet follows.

Background:  Revising a old C windows application to communicate with new instruments (while maintaining as much old code as possible), which requires the addition of new features.  In this case I am copying file names from a directory into a 2D array to populate a list of the file names.

While debugging, the program gets to the realloc call (the second realloc, as the first is skipped by the if statement) and then breaks with the error which precedes the code snippet below.

At the time of realloc, WFMLIST has been allocated, with the first element initialized to 0, and NbItemWFMLIST = 1.  So my question is, does anybody know why this error might be occurring? The memory allocation and reallocation worked before I added the directory searching and copying components.  Is it DLL releated?  I have tried many things (suggestions from similar errors on Stackoverflow), including replacing the realloc with a free() and then calloc() and received the same error.
Also, ffd is correctly finding the directory and providing the appropriate string in ffd.cFileName.

Please let me know if I can provide more information. Thanks.

> HEAP[vhf.exe]: Heap block at 01068980 modified at 01068989 past
>   requested size of 1 Windows has triggered a breakpoint in vhf.exe.
>
> This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in
>   vhf.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded.
>
> This may also be due to the user pressing F12 while vhf.exe has focus.

```
char  **WMFLIST=NULL;
long int    NbItemWFMLIST = 0;



unsigned int        playback_bytes;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA     ffd;                                        //Added for directory search
    LARGE_INTEGER       filesize;                                   //
    TCHAR               szDir[MAX_PATH];                            //
    TCHAR               *pwrkDir;
    size_t              length_pwrkDir;

HANDLE hFind = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;


pwrkDir = (TCHAR *)calloc(5, sizeof(TCHAR));


if(WFMLIST==NULL)
{
    WFMLIST=(char **)calloc(NbItemWFMLIST,sizeof(char *));
    if(WFMLIST != NULL)
    {
        WFMLIST[0]=(char *)calloc(13,sizeof(char));
        if(WFMLIST[0]==NULL)
        {
            MessageBox(hWnd,"CALLOC WMLIST[0]==NULL","Memory allocation error",MB_OK);
            NbItemWFMLIST=0;
            return(0);                             **error check 
        }
        else
        {
            NbItemWFMLIST=1;
            sprintf_s(&WFMLIST[NbItemWFMLIST-1][0],MAX_PATH,"\0");
        }

    }
    else
    {
        **error
    }

}
else
{
    WFMLIST = (char **)realloc((void *) WFMLIST,sizeof(char *));
    if(WFMLIST==NULL)
    {
        **error check
    }
    else
    {
        NbItemWFMLIST=1;
        sprintf(&WFMLIST[NbItemWFMLIST-1][0],"\0");
    }

}

if((tawg->status = GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH,pwrkDir))==SIG_SUCCESS)     //Locate the current working directory
{
    **Error check
}

sprintf_s(pwrkDir, MAX_PATH, "%s\\Waveforms", pwrkDir);                     //Append directory with Waveform folder


strcpy(szDir, pwrkDir);
strcat(szDir,"\\*");

hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
{
    **error check
} 

while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
    {
        if (ffd.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
    **error check
        }
        else
        {
    WFMLIST=(char **)realloc((void*)WFMLIST,((NbItemWFMLIST+1)*sizeof(char *)));

    if (WFMLIST[NbItemWFMLIST]==NULL)
    {
        **error
    }
    else
    {
        WFMLIST[NbItemWFMLIST]=(char *)calloc(13,sizeof(char));

                    if (WFMLIST[NbItemWFMLIST]==NULL)
        {
                        **error
            }
            else            
                    {
            sprintf(&WFMLIST[NbItemWFMLIST][0],"%s",ffd.cFileName);
                NbItemWFMLIST=NbItemWFMLIST+1;
        }           
    }                    
     }
```

}

Comment: In the first call to `calloc`, `NbItemWFMLIST` is equal to `0`. Which is an undefined behavior (could return either NULL or some unusable pointer)

Comment: Thank you @NoWiS. The heap error no longer occurs.  The error does come up when I free the allocated pwrkDir immediately following the code in the above post:  `free((void *)pwrkDir);`

Comment: But I have fixed that as well. Thanks.  I am assuming that the reason the original error occurred what because the code was originally compiled in VS '95 and worked but when compiled with VS'10 the realloc returned an unusable pointer causing heap corruption